# how to load timestamp column from table to csv file

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one oracle table which is having a date column with `timestamp(6)` datatype:

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss  (ex:2/9/2012 7:09:36.433636 PM)
```

I want to import it to one csv file.
Its appearing like `09-FEB-12 07.09.36.316529 PM` format - note inplace of `':'`,its coming as `'.'` for timestamp, how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to import?

Comment: "import it ***to** one csv file*" Are you saving the data into a CSV file or are you saving the data *from* a file **into** the table? If you are *creating* a file (i.e. exporting the data), how do you create that file? Which tool do you use? What is the SQL statement that is used for the export?

Comment: It's not clear what issue you actually want resolving.